# C++: Linked list and pointer fun

Tags: c++, pointers, linked-list

There is one thing regarding the usage of pointers here I do not understand `Cell *curr = head;` here takes the address of `head` and what does it do with it?

```
Cell *ConvertToListIter(Vector<int>& vector)
{
    Cell *head = new Cell;
    head->next = NULL;
    head->value = vector[0];
    Cell *curr = head;

    for (int i = 1; i < vector.size(); i++) {
        Cell *newCell = new Cell;
        newCell->next = NULL;
        newCell->value = vector[i];
        curr->next = newCell;
        newCell = curr;
    }

    return head;
}
```

Comment: `curr` is always a pointer to the last element in the list, so you can easily append the new node.

Comment: @DanielFischer, or at least it's supposed to be... there's a bug in this code.

Comment: @MarkRansom It wasn't there when I glanced. Truth.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Cell *curr = head;`  does not take the *address* of `head` -- it takes the **value** of `head`.  It just so happens that `head` is a pointer:

```
Cell *head = new Cell;
```

So, after `Cell *curr = head;` has executed, both `curr` and `head` point to the same thing.

**Edit** per your comment:

> So if i then delete one of them it will affect both? they point to the
>   same address in memory, not two copies of the same value yes?

That's correct.  The two pointers point to a single object in memory.  That object needs to be `delete`ed only once.  In fact, attempting to `delete` it twice will result in Undefined Behavior, and very often it will crash your program.

Comment: So if i then delete one of them it will affect both? they point to the same address in memory, not two copies of the same value yes?

Answer (score 1):

A pointer is holding a memory address therefore value of a pointer is a location in memory. When you use assignment operator on a pointer the value of that pointer is copied into another pointer. Therefore the new pointer will point to the same memory location as the first pointer was pointing.

Imagine a copy assignment on primary types :

```
int i = 1;
int j = i;
```

both values of `i` and `j` will be 1. This is also the case for pointers. So the code

```
Cell *head = new Cell;
Cell *curr = head;
```

will result in both `head` and `curr` to point to address of `new Cell`.